# Supremum of the Support of a Distribution Function

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, supremum-and-infimum

I am given the following definition of the right endpoint $x_F$ of the distribution function $F$:

$x_F = sup\{x \in \mathbb R: F(x) < 1\}$

I know that the right endpoint of a discrete uniform distribution $\mathcal U[1,5]$ is $x_F = 5$. However, this does not make sense to me with respect to the definition above.

The set of which we take the supremum in this example is {1,2,3,4}. As there exists a maximum which is part of the set, the supremum and maximum of the set are the same and $= 4$.

What do I miss here?

Comment: $F(4.9)=P (X\leq 4.9)=P(X\leq 4)=\dfrac{4}{5}<1$; the same works for every number in $[4,5)$.

Comment: @JulioPuerta I see, thank you. But the support of a discrete distribution consists of integer values. Is 4.9 even possible? E.g. the calculator gives an error when trying something different than an integer.

Comment: The support is the set of $x$ such that the density function, $f_X$, is strictly positive. The cdf, $F$, is always defined in $\mathbb{R}$, regardless of the variable.

Comment: @JulioPuerta Alright, thanks a lot for your reply!